# ThinkPad X61 wireless failure

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, thinkpad

With a ThinkPad X61 and Lubuntu 14.04.1, wireless fails to connect but Ethernet is AOK.
Multiple SSIDs are seen, in tests at multiple locations, but entering their keys do not enable connection.
Open access points also fail.
Same key works well on other Thinkpad. 
MAC address filtering is not on in the gateway (SMC D3GNV).
Problem replicated with a different distro booted from flashdrive.

`sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` fails with

> modprobe: **FATAL: Module mac80211 is in use,**
>   modprobe: FATAL: Error running remove command for iwlwifi

```
sudo modprobe -r iwl4965
```

and

```
sudo modprobe iwl4965
```

both execute with no errors or messages,

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

wants me to pick SSID and give WPA key. But, that does not fix problem, issue persists.

rfkill returns:

> 0:hci0: Bluetooth
>      Soft blocked: no
>      Hard blocked: no
>   1:tcacpi_bluetooth_sw:Bluetooth
>       Soft blocked: no
>       Hard blocked: no
>   2:phy0:Wireless LAN
>    Soft blocked: no
>    Hard blocked: no

Tried this, rebooted, still fails:

> sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-dkms
>   sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

What's my next step? Other logs linked below.

[dmesg](http://pastebin.com/LPgjueF7)
[lsmod](http://pastebin.com/5weMvcJi)
[syslog](http://pastebin.com/ekEVCAmt)
[wireless-info.txt](http://pastebin.com/8htAy3fk) (from wireless_script as per [https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos](https://askubuntu.com/425155))

Comment: Your next step is to check the logs to find the cause of the wireless key not working...

Comment: It is also possible that you have MAC address filtering on the router, might want to check. Also see if you can log into another wifi router or your own with WPA disabled.

Comment: So has this been resolved?  It has an accepted answer that makes it look like the question has been correctly answered.  If you are looking for another answer I would suggest you unaccept the current answer and explain in your question why the current answer no longer applies to your current situation.

Comment: Yes, it has been resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I might not provide the exact solution to the problem right now, because your question is missing relevant information, here's some things you can do to troubleshoot the problem and perhaps include them into the question, so that other users can help you.

**What can you include into your question?**

- Script output from [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What
  information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)
- Ouput of `/var/log/syslog`. Try reproducing the problem and note the
  time when you do it. After you go through the whole process, read the
  syslog. The recent events are all at the end of file, so you might
  want to do something like `cat /var/log/syslog | tail -n50` to list
  last 50 lines in that file, but you can change that number as needed.
- Output of `lsmod` ( perhaps a driver isn't loading properly );
- Output of `dmesg`
- Output of `rfkill list all`

**Possible issues:**

Your ethernet works, but wireless doesn't. So it may well be issue with wireless card ( failiing hardware ), with wireless drivers, or wireless configuration.  But until we know what's in your syslog, we probably won't be able to pin-down the issue. There are wireless dongles, which you could use to test whether or not this is wireless card issue, but the better way IMHO would be to boot on a live USB, and see if that works.

Comment: another thing you can include is `rfkill list all`

Comment: @K7AAY Yup,  I've looked through it today. So far I haven't found anything I could identify as possible cause. I'll keep looking, maybe other's will suggest something,too

Comment: Actually solved by opening Network Manager and manually changing the name of the SSID then entering password on Security tab. Last used when visiting a Hilton, their SSID was in there. Replacing that with my home SSID and entering the password solved it. TY, Serg!

Comment: So what you're saying is that network manager wasn't taking your config for your network but it took an edited file for Hilton ? So I think the issue could've been solved long ago if you deleted all those configs in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ and tried reconnecting again.  It's equivalent of "forget the connection" on android. Try to edit hilton config again, save and delete config file for your network,  then try reconnecting to your network.

Comment: Sure. Had I known to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The iwlwifi module doesn't work well with all Wifi adapters.
Please try this following workaround:

1. Open the terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi`
3. `sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`

If this solved the problem, please make these changes:

1. `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`
2. add the line: `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`
3. Save file
4. Restart the PC.

If not, please let us know.

Comment: you have couple other modules, iwl4965 and iwlegacy . Does removing and reinstalling them has any effect ?

Comment: From what i see in your dmesg, iwl4965 is the actual module related to your card. Try removing and reinserting that, then restart the network manager for good measure

Comment: `sudo modprobe -r iwl4965` first, if you get no warnings/erros there, do `sudo modprobe iwl4965` . I'd do `sudo service network-manager restart` for good measure as well

Comment: No warnings or errors on 'sudo modprobe -r iwl4965' nor 'sudo modprobe iwl4965' , and 'sudo service network-manager restart' prompts me to select the SSID and provide password. However, that does not fix anything, issue persists.

Answer (score -1):

I would check router settings.  First make sure it is set for 11 b/g/n and not 11n only, then check security/encryption settings and have it set to WPA2 only with no WEP or TKIP enabled and allow it to broadcast the SSID as hiding it doesn't make the network more secure.  I would also change the channel the router is on to one not being used, here is the list of used channels from the wifi script

```
Channel occupancy:
```

9   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
  2   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
  3   APs on   Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
  4   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
  1   APs on   Frequency:5.765 GHz (Channel 153)</pre></code>

Then I would go into Network Manager and set the IPv6 settings for your connections to ignore

Comment: This is polishing the cannonballs, Already said this happens at multiple locations, including open WLANs. As to altering the settings, well, that's the Comcast standard setup, which undoubtedly is improvable, but I need to get the PC connecting before I optimize their gateway's configuration. First things first.